# ASIHTTPRequest crashing when setting delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

It will be probably a simple problem, but I have been staring on this for a while now and I can't find it!

I have a SOAPRequest class like following:

```
@interface SoapRequest : NSObject

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURL *endPoint;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *soapAction;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *passWord;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *postData;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSObject *handler;
@property SEL action;

+ (SoapRequest*) create: (NSObject*) target endPoint: (NSString*) endPoint action: (SEL) action soapAction: (NSString*) soapAction postData: (NSString*) postData;

- (id)sendSynchronous;
- (void) send;

@end
```

Implementation like following:

```
@synthesize endPoint = _endPoint, soapAction = _soapAction, userName = _userName, passWord = _passWord, postData = _postData, action = _action, handler = _handler;

+ (SoapRequest*) create: (NSObject*) target endPoint: (NSString*) endPoint action: (SEL) action soapAction: (NSString*) soapAction postData: (NSString*) postData
{
    SoapRequest *request = [[SoapRequest alloc] init];
    request.endPoint = [NSURL URLWithString:endPoint];
    request.soapAction = soapAction;
    request.handler = target;
    request.action = action;
    request.postData = postData;

    return [request autorelease];
}
```

And my send function:

```
- (void) send
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:self.endPoint];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.postData length]]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];

    if(self.soapAction)
    {
        [request addRequestHeader:@"soapAction" value:self.soapAction];
    }

    [request appendPostData:[self.postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

I do have the default ASIHTTPRequest methods to listen for error or finish, my finish looks as following:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [self.handler performSelector:self.action];
}
```

The case is, it crashes when I want to make this class a delegate for the ASIHTTPRequest, [request setDelegate:self]. I figured it has something to do with the Autoreleasing in the first function. But I don't have any idea how to fix it!

Edit:

This is how I init my SoapRequest:

```
- (SoapRequest*) DefinedEntities: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action
{

// some data inits

    SoapRequest *request = [SoapRequest create: _target endPoint:endPoint action:_action soapAction:soapAction postData:xmlString];
    [request send];

    return request;
}
```

And this i init as following:

```
Metadata *service = [[Metadata alloc] init];
[service DefinedEntities:self action:@selector(MetadataFinished:)];
```

Comment: Please run your app in the debugger with NSZombies enabled, and add into youe question a stack trace for the first call to an invalid object.

Comment: What happens when you replace 'return [request autorelease]' with 'return request'?

Comment: Then it works, i already know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retaining was indeed a good option, I found some typo's in my code and figured out what i did wrong already.

I had to do with the class in-between:

```
- (SoapRequest*) DefinedEntities: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action
{

// some data inits

    SoapRequest *request = [SoapRequest create: _target endPoint:endPoint action:_action soapAction:soapAction postData:xmlString];
    [request send];

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem like you. The problem is, it gets deallocated before the delegate method gets called. Simply put a `retain` in your start method and a `release` in your finished method (and don't forget to release it in the error methods). This will let the object at life as long as the request is performing.

Comment: yep thats true. But nowadays you shouldn't use `ASIHTTP` either ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please post the code where you're creating the instance of a SOAPRequest object using:

```
+ (SoapRequest*) create: (NSObject*) target endPoint: (NSString*) endPoint action: (SEL) action soapAction: (NSString*) soapAction postData: (NSString*) postData;
```

You may need to retain it. As an aside, you should use 'id' instead of NSObject* for your target parameter, as your target will not be an instance of NSObject (it will be a subclass) of sorts.

Comment: Is this actually returning an instance? Does self.endPoint exist? ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:self.endPoint];

Comment: In this you can see everything, and the endpoints exists, but i deleted the link for privacy purposes

Comment: You can see "// some data inits" here I put instead of var inits an comment!

Comment: What I'm saying is, set a breakpoint on the [request setDelegate:self]; line, and check that *request is not nil.

Comment: request is not empty there (which i mean the request of ASIHTTPRequest *request), it goes trough the whole "send" function. But i guess somewhere it goes wrong with finding the delegated methods (for example: requestFinished). I think it has something to do with the autorelease I do.

Answer (score 1):

If the crash only occurs when you set self (SOAPRequest) as the delegate, are you sure that self isn't being deallocated (then the bad access occurs when the ASIHTTPRequest calls the did finish on its delegate which no longer exists).

```
- (SoapRequest*) DefinedEntities: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action
{

// some data inits

    SoapRequest *request = [SoapRequest create: _target endPoint:endPoint action:_action soapAction:soapAction postData:xmlString];
    [request send];

    return request;
}
```

When you do this, request is autoreleased and you should make sure it is retained by someone until the ASIHTTPRequest it sent has finished or failed.

Comment: whoever calls the - (SoapRequest*) DefinedEntities: (id) _target action: (SEL) _action method.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have a self releasing class like this soap request class, do your httprequest async and let the class auto release itself when needed? Don't get me wrong, i am a beginner in objective c!

Comment: @Wesso request needs to stay alive for as long as the ASIHTTPRequest is running, so that it can receive the delegate callback. The system doesn't know that and it will deallocate request when it goes out of scope, you must ensure that it doesn't (by retaining request).

Comment: you could call [self retain]; when creating the ASIHTTPRequest, then [self release]; after the delegate callback has been performed.